# check for "errors" or "ORA-"

Tags: shell-script, scripting, environment-variables, hp-ux

I want to check for "errors" or "ORA-" in $Y. If there is an error then exit

```
Y=`sqlplus -s user/passwd<< EOF
exec test_Proc;
exit;
EOF`
if [ echo $Y | awk '/ERROR/ || /ORA-/' ] ; then
  exit 1
fi
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running `bash` you can do it with regexp matching:

```bash
if [[ $Y =~ (ERROR|ORA-) ]]; then
    echo error
fi
```

Or, if you insist, you can also do it with `awk`:

```bash
if ! printf '%s\n' "$Y" | awk '/ERROR|ORA-/ {exit 1}'; then
    echo error
fi
```

The point is, `awk` uses regular expressions, not shell expression logic.

The simplest approach is probably to just use `grep`:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$Y" | egrep -q 'ERROR|ORA-' && echo error
```

Comment: `awk` has _both_ regexps _and_ C-like expressions including `&&` and `||` so either your pattern or the OP's works. What matters is either have awk set the exit status for shell `if`as you do, or let awk output the match and _capture_ that output for shell test: `if [ -n "$(printf...|awk '/ERROR|ORA-/' )" ]`